# I just upgraded PostgreSQL with yum on Amazon Linux, now PostgreSQL won't start. What do I do?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, linux

I just ran `yum update` on my Amazon Linux instance as part of an upgrade to 2012.09 and it upgraded PostgreSQL from 9.1 to 9.2. Now PostgreSQL won't start. What do I do?

(This is a very incomplete question because it's just here to provide somewhere to post the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon's packages for PostgreSQL will upgrade from 9.1 to 9.2 as if that was a normal minor update. It isn't; see the [PostgreSQL version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), which makes it clear that the major version is "x.y", eg "9.1", "9.2", etc. This version policy may be weird and perhaps unwise, but it's also widely understood and something you would expect packagers to understand. The [documentation for upgrading a PostgreSQL cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/upgrading.html) explains this point very clearly.

The Amazon packages don't seem to get that, and just upgrade PostgreSQL. This is a very bad idea. Upgrades can involve downtime and backward-compatibility-breaking changes. C extension functions must be recompiled. A dump and reload may be required if [`pg_upgrade`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgupgrade.html) can't be used with your database. Even if `pg_upgrade` can be used, downtime can be significant.

See [Amazon's severe PostgreSQL packaging blunder](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/297-Amazons-serious-PostgreSQL-packaging-blunder.html) by Andrew Dunstan, and [this bug report on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=397693).

Amazon <strike>has</strike> *had* a [FAQ entry](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#postgresql9) for this, but it's really the wrong answer. The right answer is "don't upgrade without asking!". Not only that, but doing a `pg_upgrade` can take some preparation and won't work for all databases. This is really bad advice. (They seem to have silently removed this FAQ entry now, that'll help those customers who're still updating from older versions!)

Nonetheless, `pg_upgrade` is your only easy option once this has happened. If you can't use it, you'll need to roll back to PostgreSQL 9.1, `pg_dump` your DBs and `pg_dumpall --globals-only` as well, then install 9.2 and load the dumps. See [upgrading a PostgreSQL cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/upgrading.html)

Comment: Andrew Dunstan's blog is returning blank pages for some reason, but it looks like that post was captured here:  http://www.lephpfacile.com/annuaire/rss/70-planet-postgresql/511848-andrew-dunstan-amazon-s-serious-postgresql-packaging-blunder.

Comment: Craig, can you confirm that Amazon has fixed this behavior? Looks to me like the PostgreSQL 9 packages in the amzn-main repo are now named with the first point, currently postgresql92 and postgresql93. I assume this means that `yum update` would take you from 9.2.7 to 9.2.9, for example, but not to 9.3.x.

Comment: It looks like they have, but I haven't personally verified it since I don't use Amazon Linux given a choice. The problem could still exist if their RPMs declare `Obsoletes: ` properties, even if the package names are different, though I doubt they would've done that if they've bothered to finally separate the packages. It's easy enough to test and see.

Comment: On a new machine built with a 2014.09 AMI, I had it install postgresql92 at 9.2.9.  `yum list updates` does not show any updates available, even though `yum list available postgresql*` shows that postgresql93 packages are available. I may continue to use the exclusion in `yum.conf` so I can control the in-between patches as well.